# It seems that sidekiq doesn't support actioncable in Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

So I'm trying to broadcast a message in one of the jobs. the job is being executed but it's not broadcasting the message.
Is it because actioncable requires Puma to perform message broadcasting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I guess the reason why it wasn't working was because the cable adapter wasn't set to redis in `config/cable.yml`

Comment: Can you help-me how to do this? I don't understand what I need to do em my config/cable.yml